# Custom query converts dt_wstr in nchar sql type

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I create in a look up ssis this custom query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
from (select * from [dbo].[TyrePoints]) [refTable]
where ([refTable].[brand] LIKE ? OR [refTable].[brand] = '*')

ORDER BY [refTable].[priority] DESC
```

the "?" is replaced by a dt_wstr(20) variable and [refTable].[brand] is a nvarchar(20) field in the db.

When I check the result of this query with sql profiler I get :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 1 * 
from (select * from [dbo].[TyrePoints]) [refTable]
where ([refTable].[brand] LIKE @P1 OR [refTable].[brand] = ''*'')
ORDER BY [refTable].[priority] DESC',N'@P1 nchar(20)',N'test                '
```

Why SSIS converts my dt_wstr type in nchar?

How can I have a result with a nvarchar type?

Comment: Have you tried using a convert ot cast statement? Try googling T-SQL convert and T-SQL Cast And read the top hit after searching.

Comment: in the parameter section you pick the datatype each item is set to.  Review what you picked from the dropdown.